# Are the commas with the word additionally correctly placed? and what article should I use in the end of the sentence?

Tags: articles, commas

Despite these drawbacks, this may be a well-accepted and, additionally, environmentally-friendly solution in *a/the* close future.

Comment: not only....but also would work. in a not-to-distant future

Answer (score 1):

> Despite these drawbacks, this may be a well-accepted and, additionally, environmentally friendly solution in the near future.

- No hyphen in "environmentally friendly".
- Use the article "the".
- Replace "close" with "near" (much more idiomatic).

Comment: Why a second indefinite article?  There is only one noun to which either of the two indefinite articles can attach.

Comment: I feel the punctuation and addition of “additional” sort of separates the two, and so I introduced “an” as I feel like otherwise it reads or *feels* as “a environmentally friendly”, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Try taking "additionally" out and see how it stands then:  a well-accepted and an environmentally friendly solution".  Is that one solution or two?

Comment: I see what you mean; I’ll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just remove *additionally* and rephrase the sentence as

> Despite these drawbacks, this may be a well-accepted, environment-friendly solution in the close future.

But if you want to stick to the word *additional*, which I'd deem redundant, then I'd rephrase the sentence as

> Despite these drawbacks, this may be a well-accepted and additionally, an environment-friendly solution in the close future.